# How do I create an application that transparently overlays the iPhone home screen?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I would like to create an iPhone application that, after starting via the home screen, transparently overlays the home screen.  The application itself would not appear to have launched.

Is this possible?  If so, how?

Comment: Can you go into a little more detail about the intent of your application?  I have a feeling that, whatever it is, it won't be kosher with the App Store guidelines.  If you're planning to develop this for jailbroken phones, though, that would be different.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have two applications running at the same time in this manner, so no, it's not possible.

i.e.: You can't have a completely transparent application running visually on top of the [SpringBoard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpringBoard) app.

Comment: You can test it by making a new Xcode project and then changing the `window.alpha` property to 0. You just get a black screen. What's the purpose of the app intended to be? There might be a different solution...

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can do it, all you need to do is take a screen shot of your home screen and you can put the pic in the app using `UIImageView`. So when the user clicks on your app icon it will show the home screen.

Comment: What he wanted to show home screen in his app.I think this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: sorry but you cannot make an application transparent to show the home screen or show any other screen below it.